# power of a product in non Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

To show $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$ is true, I use the commutative property which implies the group I'm working with is an Abelian group.
Is there a way to show $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$ meets in non-abelian groups or it is simply false?

Comment: It is not true in general for nonabelian groups. In fact, you can have groups in which $a$, $b$, and $ab$ have arbitrary orders, whereas in a group in which $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, the order of $ab$ would have to divide the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.   The first group where this does not hold in general is $S_3$, since $\bigl( (1,2)(1,3) )^2 = (1,3,2)^2 = (1,2,3)$, but $(1,2)^2(1,3)^2 = e$. (I compose permutations right to left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed "simply false" in non-abelian groups; indeed, the case $n = 2$, if true, asserts that

$(ab)(ab) = (ab)^2 = a^2 b^2 \Longrightarrow ab = ba, \tag 1$

which is of course essentially the definition of "abelian group".

Answer (score 4):

It's not generally true that for any $a,b \in G, (ab)^2 = a^2b^2$ if $G$ is not abelian. For example take in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, the group of $2$-by-$2$ invertible matrices under matrix multiplication, $a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. We see that 
$
(ab)^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.
$

and

$
a^2b^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & - 2 \\ 0 & - 1\end{bmatrix}.
$

We see $(ab)^2 \neq a^2b^2$.